# Why is a polynomial in $z,\bar z$ analytic iff it does not involve monomials $z^i\bar z^j$ with $j\ge1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I have encountered some note on complex analysis:
**In particular, given a polynomial in the real variables x and y , with
complex coefficients, these properties tell us that the polynomial
is analytic on C precisely when, in its representation as a linear
combination of terms $z^{j} \overline{z}^{j}$ , terms involving $ \overline{z}^{}$ do not occur.**
what does it mean?Could you give me some formulas?
[image]

Comment: We don't know what $z$ is in this context. Perhaps you can post the whole page so that we see some examples?

Comment: Maybe "involving $\overline{z}$" (see [MathJax tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations))? Seems related to [Cauchy-Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).

Comment: Does your textbook (btw, please name it) state, in a previous page, that $f$ is analytic iff $\bar\partial f=0$?

Comment: Are you aware that the family of all monomials $z^m\overline z^n$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Do you understand how a polynomial in $x,y$ can be represented as a linear combination of terms $z^i\bar z^j$? (btw, please correct the misprint $z^{\color{red}j}\bar z^j$ your textbook). If you do, then you should edit your post to show your attempts (using the properties you quoted)  to show that the condition mentionned in the title of your post is necessary and sufficient for such a polynomial $\sum_{0\le i,j\le d}a_{i,j}z^i\bar z^j$ to be analytic.